# Why does PHP add additional slash to variable?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, character-encoding, char

I am working on a French character conversation issue.  When the PHP receives an É, it converts it to \xc3\x89 (UTF-8 hex, basically).  É is stored in the mySQL database as \u00c9 (UTF-16 hex, basically).  I need to convert the former to the later so that they match.  json_encode() should work

```
//$criteria is \xc3\x89
error_log("criteria vvvvvvvvvvvvv");
error_log($criteria);

$clean = json_encode($criteria, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);  

error_log("json_encode() vvvvvvvvvvvvvv");
error_log($clean);
```

but, in the error log, this outputs:

```
[Fri Aug 23] criteria vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv, 
[Fri Aug 23 \xc3\x89
[Fri Aug 23] json_encode(criteria) vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv, 
[Fri Aug 23] "\\u00c9"
```

Why is the extra slash added? It's keeping the characters from matching.  How do I not have that?  Is it Apache? ZF1? PHP 7.0.1? ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Can you try with something other than `error_log`? It’s unclear what extra processing that entails.

Comment: For what it's worth `\u00c9` is not UTF-16, but it's a unicode codepoint. This doesn't solve your problem in the slightest though

Comment: It's not slash. It's named backslash. From [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-unescaped-slashes) for JSON constants: "JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES - Don't escape /." So it isn't related to backslash.

Answer (score 1):

When you call json_encode() on raw Unicode characters (\x3c\x89), it will try to convert it to a Unicode character first, which is the string "\u00c9".

Then, in order to store that value into a JSON string, it needs to make sure that the "\" before the "u" is preserved when decoding later.

If it DID NOT add the extra slash, then when a JSON parser read that value later on, it would see "\u" as an escaped "u" character, and you would end up with a string "u00c9" which is just a bunch of letters and numbers, not a Unicode character.

So to ensure that it decodes back to "\u00c9", it has to be encoded as "\\u00c9"

If you don't want json_encode() to try to convert the raw bytes to a Unicode character first, then you can use the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE flag to keep it as the raw data:

```
<?php
$rawBytes = "É";
echo json_encode($rawBytes) . "\n"; // Output: "\u00c9"
echo json_encode($rawBytes, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) . "\n"; // Output: "É"
```